# Where to ask about MD5 collisions that are conceptual not programmatic

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question that pertains specifically to whether collisions are more or less likely under one set of conditions vs another when hashing using MD5.

There are a lot of MD5 tagged questions on Stack Exchange, and although this is connected with the use of MD5 by a third party in (python) code, this is a conceptual question not a programming question.

Where would be the best site to ask such a question?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a question for [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://cryptography.stackexchange.com).

> Cryptography Stack Exchange is for asking questions about the mathematics and properties of cryptographic systems, their analysis ("cryptanalysis") and subsidiary topics that generally make up cryptology, such as random number generation.

<sub>(from their [help center](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))</sub>

They have [quite a few questions about MD5](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/md5) already, so maybe your question is already answered.